# Creating DLL excluding std objects

Tags: c++, dll, mingw, std

My library makes use of std::unordered_map and is also compiled with my dll. My question is; is there a way to keep it out of my dll and link it to the library containing the unordered map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unordered_map` is a header only library, there is no binary library that can be linked at runtime that will provide it.

Technically you can go out of your way to split the headers into declaration and definition, use the declaration for the dll, and then built a different dll with the explicit template instantiations that you used in the main dll, but that will not remove the need to provide the compiled `unordered_map`, but rather split what you have as a single dll it in two.

Comment: I don't like pain =(. My DLL isn't big. It's just 640 kb but I wouldn't mind keeping things seperated. It will do. Not worth the trouble! Thanks.

Comment: @Sidar: There might be other ways of reducing the size of the DLL, changing compiler flags for example, might reduce the number of symbols that make it into the binary. Not having debug symbols will also reduce the size quite a bit. Note that (I should have said this in the answer), one advantage of templates is that they are easily *inlined* by the compiler potentially reducing code size (for small functions) and increasing efficiency. Separating the implementation will effectively inhibit inlining (other than whole program optimizations) and the behavior will probably be worse.

Comment: I've basically turned off debugging for my dll . But i'll check into it. Thanks